# Firebase Cloud Functions trigger at 00

Tags: firebase, function, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Hei guys. I was looking for a way to trigger my function every hour at 00 minute. The way it works now it depends by the time the function has been uploaded at, so if I upload it at 13:45, it will first trigger at 14:45. What should I do to make it trigger at 14:00?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the (new) feature that allows scheduling Cloud Functions by using `functions.pubsub.schedule().onRun()`.

In your case you would use a [Unix Crontab configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions?authuser=0#write_a_scheduled_function) as follows:

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 * * * *')
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every hour at hh:00');
  return null;
});
```

See a crontab configurator here: https://crontab.guru